# Linked list error: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'head'

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have to write a linked list for a college assignment, I've followed my instruction to a T as far as I can see.

I can't figure out why I'm getting the errors, It has something to do with the pointers declared in my listOfDouble class,

I'v searched through the answers on stack relating to the error message and a few posts suggested it could be an issue with my #include, and that I should be declaring the class instead: class ListOfDoubles;

I've tried replacing my includes to no avail.

I'm stumped on this, bare in mind I am a student, so my mistake could end up being trivial.

Edit: It was trivial.

ListOfDoubles.h

```
#ifndef LISTOFDOUBLES_H
#define LISTOFDOUBLES_H

class ListOfDoubles{
public:
    ListOfDoubles();
    ~ListOfDoubles();
    void insert(double);
    void displaylist();
    double deleteMostRecent();
private:
    DoubleListNodePtr head;
    DoubleListNodePtr temp;
    DoubleListNodePtr newNode;
};

#endif
```

DoubleListNode.h

```
#ifndef DOUBLELISTNODE_H
#define DOUBLELISTNODE_H

class DoubleListNode{
    friend class ListOfDoubles;
public:
    DoubleListNode(double);
private:
    double data;
    DoubleListNode *next;
};
typedef DoubleListNode* DoubleListNodePtr;
#endif
```

Implementation

```
#include "ListOfDoubles.h"
#include "DoubleListNode.h"
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;

ListOfDoubles::ListOfDoubles()
    :head(NULL){

};
DoubleListNode::DoubleListNode(double data)
    :data(data){

};
void ListOfDoubles::insert(double data){

    newNode = new DoubleListNode(data);
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
};
void ListOfDoubles::displaylist(){

    DoubleListNodePtr temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL){
        cout << temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
};
double ListOfDoubles::deleteMostRecent(){

};
ListOfDoubles::~ListOfDoubles(){
    delete head;
    delete temp;
    delete newNode
};
```

main

```
#include "ListOfDoubles.h" 
#include "DoubleListNode.h"
#include<iostream>


int main()
{

    ListOfDoubles list1;

    list1.insert(25);
    list1.displaylist();

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Errors

```
1>  main.cpp
1>d:\college\semester 5\algorithms and data structures\lab_6b\lab_6b\lab_6b\listofdoubles.h(13): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'head'
1>d:\college\semester 5\algorithms and data structures\lab_6b\lab_6b\lab_6b\listofdoubles.h(13): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\college\semester 5\algorithms and data structures\lab_6b\lab_6b\lab_6b\listofdoubles.h(14): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'temp'
1>d:\college\semester 5\algorithms and data structures\lab_6b\lab_6b\lab_6b\listofdoubles.h(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\college\semester 5\algorithms and data structures\lab_6b\lab_6b\lab_6b\listofdoubles.h(15): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'newNode'
1>d:\college\semester 5\algorithms and data structures\lab_6b\lab_6b\lab_6b\listofdoubles.h(15): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: how about including `DoubleListNodePtr.h` in `ListOfDoubles.h` ? or at least providing forward declaration and typedef for that pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using DoubleListNodePtr in ListOfDoubles.h while it's defined in DoubleListNode.h, hence the compiler doesn't know what type it is ("missing type specifier"). Include DoubleListNode.h in ListOfDoubles.h.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answer

1.You need to include `DoubleListNode.h` in `ListOfDoubles.h`

2.You are missing ";" on line #34 in implementation file.

```
delete newNode
```

should be

```
delete newNode;
```

Comment: Yeah I caught that after I included the DoubleListNode.h in ListOfDoubles.h, I'm a bit frustrated, I had thought of trying that a while ago and I completely forgot to.